# Build a library for Swift and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, build, static-libraries

I need to make a library with swift that support both swift and object c project (also support xcode 5), this will be a distribution library (do not share source code). There are two ways to do this: create a Cocoa Touch Framework or create a Cocoa Touch Static Library. I make some research, but still find out the solution. It seems the Cocoa Touch Framework not support to buid a distribution library, and I'm not sure the Cocoa Touch Static Library work perfect with with Swift yet or not. Any solutions for it. Thanks.

Comment: Btw,the question title is no good, it will be better : "Build a library for Swift and Objective-C". I edit it

Comment: @Pintouch: You are right, tks.

Answer (score 1):

A very good example for this kind of library is [Realm](http://realm.io).

They both support swift and objective-c project integration. Check the repo on GitHub , and browse it : [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa)

In fact, they have all the library coded in Objective-C, and the add Support for swift specifecity with extensions on objects used by the client. (For example, check the Realm/RLMSwiftSupport.m in their repo)

**EDIT**

To access a Swift class in Objective-C, just add `@objc(MyClass)` in your Swift Class and it will be available in Objective-C files.

Read the [this](http://carlosicaza.com/swiftbooks/SwiftObjcCocoa.pdf) for more informations about Objective-C and Swift working together

Comment: I have reviewed the Realm source, they written with Object-C then support for Swift. In my case, it want to make it by Swift and support both Swift and Object-C.

Comment: Oh sorry for the misunderstood. If you want to access a Swift class from Objective-C, just add `@objc(MyClass)`in your swift class. Then this class will be available in Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as you to build one Pod library for both Swift and Objective-C, using pure code respectively without messing languages or include bridging headers. Actually I didn't try it by myself, but I came to several possible solutions:

1) To use a different branches of the same repo:

```
pod 'YourPodLib', :git => 'https://github.com/user_name/YourPodLib.git', :branch => 'objc'

pod 'YourPodLib', :git => 'https://github.com/user_name/YourPodLib.git', :branch => 'swift'
```

2) Experimenting with **Subspecs** as a way to install a subset of your library. (official cocoapods documentation: [subspec](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec) )

It probably would look like:
`pod 'YourPodLib/Swift'`

Maybe my approach is far away from being ideal, but I would be appreciate if you correct me or suggest a better idea.