# Creating a framework with mixed Swift & Objective-C code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk, package

I have a project with mixed code (objective-c and Swift) that I need to package as a framework. It also uses some external frameworks.

My umbrella header has many imports to different headers of the frameworks I use, as well as to the objective-c source code in my project (so that it's accessible by the Swift code). I also have a swift file, e.g. MyFramework.swift, that has some code that I'd like to expose to users of the framework.

The framework compiles, however, when I try to use it in another Swift project, I cannot access the contents of MyFramework.swift. That is the case even though the file exists (with the Swift source code) in the framework product!

Yet, I am able to access the objective-c code from the public headers. So I tried to write the code in MyFramework.swift in objective-c instead (MyFramework.h & MyFramework.m), because I thought it might be a problem exposing code in both objective-c and swift (though from what I read - it shouldn't be). That did the trick in terms of accessing the objects inside this class, but then I got a linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyObject", referenced from:
>         __TZFC12TestFW6MyObject20testfMS0_FCSo16UIViewControllerT_
>   in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

This actually happens for every public swift class I try to reference. I made sure these files exist in the "Compile Sources" list under Build Phases of the project settings, so that's not the problem.

I'm pretty clueless. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution to it?

Comment: Nope. I ended up creating two separate frameworks - one for Swift users and one for obj-c users. Gave up for now on creating one f/w for both.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your project there's 2 things to check.

1. Do you have the correct "valid architecture" in your project
   (1st picture below), and
2. Do you have a BridgingHeader properly
       created for working with Swift and Obj-C in the same project (2nd
       picture below)?

[image: Project Settings - Valid Architecture]

[image: Swift Compiler - Bridging Header]

Comment: The first setting you mentioned was already set correctly. I indeed was missing the bridging header in my test project, but adding it didn't help either. Still getting the linker error:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyObject", referenced from: ...
And still the swift code is not exposed to the project, this is only when using an objective-c header.

Comment: @Pintouch posted this note:  To access a Swift class in Objective-C, just add @objc(MyClass) in your Swift Class and it will be available in Objective-C files.
                                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417735/build-a-library-for-swift-and-objective-c

Comment: @E.K. There is no such thing as a bridging header in a swift framework, but there is an umbrella header, have a look here for more informations : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238761/what-is-an-umbrella-header